# Hidden three-dot (ellipses) in prolog of XML file Produced by SSRS

Tags: xml, xslt, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, hex-editors

I am generating an xml file in SSRS using the "xml file with report data" render format and a custom XSLT file which my RDL points to.

When I try to run the XML document through an XML validator, I receive the following error: "Content Is Not Allowed In Prolog., Line '1', Column '1'.
Content Is Not Allowed In Prolog"

At first I tried to look at the XML document in Notepadd++ and identify any hidden characters but nothing appeared to be out of the ordinary.

[XML FILE in Notepad++ with No Hidden Characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPHrM.jpg)

However, when I ran the file through a HEX Editor I noticed that there are three dots (periods, ellipses) that appear before the the "

[Hex Editor view of XML with Hidden Characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQ76r.jpg)

If I copy the XML text into a new text document and save it as "xml", it passes the XML validator.

How are these characters being generated and how can I prevent them from being produced in my XML document.

Comment: That a BOM (Byte Order Mark) that is present in some UTF-8 streams.  You have 2 choices: 1) Modify the process that produces the XML to not generate the BOM; 2) Preprocess the XML to remove the BOM.

Comment: And BTW, if you had Googled _"Content Is Not Allowed In Prolog"_ you would have found dozens if not hundreds of links explaining this problem and offering solutions.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I did learn there were byte order marks. I guess my question was how could I omit them from my SSRS output. I have tried modifying the XSL file that styles my XML output but was unable to do it there. I have also tried updating the reportserver.config file. Thanks for the input.

Comment: As I said, you have only two options.  At the worst you could pipe the XML through a simple script that looks for and removes the BOM, or even use `tail -c +3` if you're on a Linux or Unix variant, and you're ***sure*** the BOM will always be there.